# Binary Search Tree - Level order traversal in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I was trying out the code for level order traversal in a binary search tree using a queue and I don't know why I'm getting no output when I try to print the level order. Someone please help!

[Link to my code.](http://codepad.org/ocIVKXhf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int data;
    struct Node *right, *left;
}Node;

typedef struct
{
    int front, rear, size;
    unsigned capacity;
    Node* arr[100];
}Queue;

Queue* createQ()
{
    Queue* q = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    q->capacity = 100;
    q->front = q->size = 0; 
    q->rear = q->capacity - 1;
    return q;
}

int isEmpty(Queue* q)
{  
    return (q->size == 0); 
}
int isFull(Queue* q)
{  
    return (q->size == q->capacity);  
}
void enqueue(Queue* q, Node* item)
{
    if (isFull(q))
        return;
    q->rear = (q->rear + 1)%q->capacity;
    q->arr[q->rear] = item;
    q->size = q->size + 1;
 }


Node* dequeue(Queue* q)
{
    if (isEmpty(q))
        return NULL;
    Node* item = q->arr[q->front];
    q->front = (q->front + 1)%q->capacity;
    q->size = q->size - 1;
    return item;
}

Node* create(Node* root, int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        root->data = data;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        if(data>root->data)
        {
            root->right = create(root->right,data);
        }
        else
        {
            root->left = create(root->left,data);
        }
        return root;
    }
}
void levelorder(Node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL) return;
    else
    {
        Queue* q = createQ();
        enqueue(q,root);
        while(isEmpty(q))
        {
            Node* temp = dequeue(q);
            printf("%d ",temp->data);
            if(temp->right)
                enqueue(q,temp->right);
            else if(temp->left);
                enqueue(q,temp->left);
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int data;
    Node *root = NULL;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the elements (-1 to stop) : ");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        if(data==-1) break;
        root = create(root,data);
    }
    printf("\nPrinting the elemtents in level order : ");
    levelorder(root);
}
```

Comment: Debug it then..

Comment: Please do not post links to code stored off-site; post the code in the question.  If it is big, work on creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Then post the MCVE code.

Answer (score 2):

You have several bugs in your `levelorder` function. Please check the corrections below. I've kept your buggy line in side comment.

```
void levelorder(Node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL) return;
    else
    {
        Queue* q = createQ();
        enqueue(q,root);
        while(!isEmpty(q)) // not while(isEmpty(q)) you have to check untill Queue is non-empty
        {
            Node* temp = dequeue(q);
            printf("%d ",temp->data);
            if(temp->right)
                enqueue(q,temp->right);
            if(temp->left)  // not else if(temp->left); there can be right node and left node as well.. no semicolon
                enqueue(q,temp->left);
        }
    }
}
```

Rest of the code is okay. You should practice debugging yourself using some well-known IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In line 83, `while(isEmpty(q))` should be `while(!isEmpty(q))` because we would want to run the loop while the Queue is non-empty.

I hope I got the bug right.